# Using the font awsome sort icon which is cliked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, font-awesome

I am new to this. Here I am using the `font-awsome` `sort icons`.

```
<th scope="col">Technology<i className="fa fa-fw fa-sort sort-icon" onClick={(event) => props.sortAscending(event,'technology')}></i></th>
```

Now, Here I want to sort this data by asc or desc . Now, In this, using this way I am not able to get weather user has clicked the ascending or descending order.

So, I have checked for the `event` as well but no luck

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Do you have 2 buttons ? one for ASC and one for DESC ?

Comment: No this is the icon fa-sort

Comment: Then there's no separate asc out desc symbol. You could try and work out whether the user clicks in the upper, or lower, part of the `<i>` element, perhaps. Or use both glyphs.

Comment: then I have to do the css related things there right ?

Comment: you can also store the sorting order in the state of your component

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your component is named `SomeSortableTable`, I'd suggest you edit it so that it looks like something like this :

```
class SomeSortableTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { sortingASC: true, }
        this.sortData = this.sortData.bind(this);
    }

    sortData(event) {
         const {props, state} = this;

         if (this.state.sortingASC) {
             props.sortAscending(event, 'technology');
         }
         else {
             props.sortDescending(event, 'technology');
         }
         this.setState({sortingASC: !state.sortingASC});
    }

    render() {
        return 
            <th scope="col">Technology<i className="some-icon" onClick={(event) => this.sortData(event)}></i></th>
    }
}
```

The line `this.setState({sortingASC: !state.sortingASC});` will toggle the sorting order and keep it in memory for later use.

You can then go further and add the class `fa-flip-vertical` to your icon accordingly.